# WKWebView asks "would like to use your current location" not localized, always in english

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

Firefox, Chrome and Safari show this questions localized according to iphone language.
I can't figure out why system don't want to localize it in my app. It is not the first permission question, which can be localized in plist file, it is question for specific site, like maps.google.com
It is on device not on simulator.
How to make system to localize this alerts?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question? When you say "It is on device not on simulator", does this mean, its working fine on simulator?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work on simulator too. All examples from internet have the same result. Objective-c.

Comment: The answer is that you should localize your app to languages you want to see in this alert

Comment: Does it work after that change?

Comment: yes, add localization to storyboard or xib files

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was working in a Cordova Project and all I had to do was add this to the project .plist in Xcode.

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>es</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<array>
    <string>es</string>
</array>
```

However for Cordova it could be achieved by adding the following to a plugin in the plugin.xml file below the iOS part.

```
<edit-config target="CFBundleLocalizations" file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite">
    <array>
       <string>es</string>
   </array>
</edit-config>

<edit-config target="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion" file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite">
    <array>
        <string>es</string>
    </array>
</edit-config>
```